# How To Prevent Zoom in Chromium

Tags: kernel, 16.04, google-chrome, chromium, zooming

Condition: Artifact zoom <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>+/-</kbd> by keyboard and touchpad
Support: prevention discussed first time in 2009 [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/X0wTNQpfl2k) about *How to turn off Zoom on Chrome*
Proposal: Prevent Zoom by touchpad/keyboard in the Internet Browser by one-liner for a plugin approach
Independent: mouse

Open

- How to make an one-liner for the prevention of zoom either keyboard or touchpad?

Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Internet browsers: Chromium (`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`), Google Chrome
Linux kernel: 4.6 (report [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=622239) about why)
Linux kernel options: wl

Comment: do you have a mouse with a wheel ? (M500 of Logitech) - this would be more comfortable.

Comment: What do you mean by "one-liner"? Are you looking to make a plugin for Chrome that enables/disables the artifact zoom?

Comment: Additionally, I really don't see how this is related to the kernel.

Comment: @codingman Record the occurrance of artifact zooming in different configurations with Linux kernel 4.4 and 4.6. Note the difference. I get much less occurrances in Linux kernel 4.6 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @codingman One-liner is the goal to ease the maintenance. Other proposals are also welcome, since nothing works yet sufficiently.

Comment: Have you tried creating an extension using javascript? There is one already, but it does not prevent plain keyboard zooming, see [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-scroll-wheel-zoom/mdpfkohgfpidohkakdbpmnngaocglmhl?hl=en).